# Проблема перевода из строки в число

Tags: java

```
if( myPort.available()>0){
val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n'); 
}
fill(255);
rect(0,0,WidthForm,HeightForm);
line(0,CenterLine,WidthForm,CenterLine);
if((val!=null)&&(val!="")){
 if(f){      
   //OffSet();
   println("Val "+val);
   ValuesLight[0]=int(val);
   println("ValuesLight "+ValuesLight[0]);
   //DrawGraph();
   f=false;
 }else{
   DrawScale(val);
   f=true;
 }
```

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делайте так:

```
ValuesLight[0] = Integer.valueOf(val);
```